# How to change default sdk version in Android Studio in windows OS

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I create sample for eg:login template in android studio the project is getting created in android sdk version 23, I want to change this for all projects created in future.How to change the sdk version of android studio. Changing gradle settings after creation of project wont help since all the UI elements will be created for sdk23.Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You can choose the sdk on project setup...

Comment: It shows for min sdk not for traget sdk

Comment: **targetSdkVersion** will be always latest version of android.so you can not change get it while creating the the app if you want to change it then you have to change after **gradle** created and for that specific version you have to download repositories which suites for that version.and for every project you have to change it like i described.

Comment: The default template layout files will be created in sdk 23, Changing this will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from
 your module level `build.gradle` file

```
compileSdkVersion 23

minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

change these values and rebuild your code.

Comment: Anyway to do it before creating the project.After changing the sdk to 21 for project created in sdk 23 I'm getting layout issues each time it should be fixed, If the project is created in 21 sdk it can be avoided.

Comment: what is the issue ? please state the error properly